# Add missing left parentheses into equation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

I'm pretty stuck in finding a proper solution for a given problem, been looking for some ideas over the internet. Wasn't be able to find any.

Problem is: writing a program that takes from the standard input an expression without left parentheses and prints the equivalent infix expression with the parentheses inserted.

Given expression: `1 + 2) * 3 - 4)* 5 - 6)))`
Output: `((1 + 2) * ((3 - 4) * (5 - 6)))`

What can be the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know it's not supposed to be `1 + ((2) * 3 - ((4)* 5 - (6)))`?

Comment: Do you just want to put a left parenthesis after the following operand from the previous right parenthesis?

Comment: @lc, cause the output format has been given as an answer.

Comment: @mehdix_ This is not about the *format* at all, it's a completely different interpretation. As it stands, this question is incomplete and not answerable.

Comment: @jab, would've been easy that way! but I don' think that'll work. The algorithm should be able to parse the input, evaluate the missing parenthesis pairs.

Comment: @us2012, unfortunately this is coming from a book which is now being used by so many computer science major.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that the goal is assuming that you only parenthesize expressions, not lone numbers.

So you'll want to grab each token and toss them on a stack

```
2
+
1
```

grab the next token, which is )
now take the top three of the stack and sandwich it between those parens ( 1 + 2 ), put it back on the stack as one expression.

next push the stack looks like this

```
4
-
3
*
(1 + 2)
```

pull out the top three and put it back on the stack parenthesized
    (3-4)
    *
    (1+2)

and again

```
6
-
5
*
(3-4)
*
(1+2)
```

we hit another paren and grab the top 3 from the stack again, parenthesize and push back

```
(5-6)
*
(3-4)
*
(1+2)
```

We grab another paren, grab the top 3 from the stack again, parenthesize and push back

```
((3-4)*(5-6))
*
(1+2)
```

and again...

```
((1 + 2) * ((3 - 4) * (5 - 6)))
```

no more input, so this is our answer

Comment: wonderful, that's the way through. you were a great help @agoaj

Comment: there is a bug because the final parentheses is not balanced.